# How can I use java to send HTTP post request of a JSON array of strings?

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to implement the http post request to specified in the link: [Click here for the link.](http://sentiment.vivekn.com/docs/api/)
How can I do so with Java?

```
String url = "http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/text/";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

String urlParameters = "Text to classify";

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

How do I modify this as to send a JSON array of texts as described in the link and retrieve the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    URL url = new URL("http://sentiment.vivekn.com/api/batch/");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);//5 secs
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);//5 secs

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());  
    out.write(
            "[ " +
            "\"the fox jumps over the lazy dog\"," +
            "\"another thing here\" " +
            "]");
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    int res = connection.getResponseCode();

    System.out.println(res);


    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = null;
    while((line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    connection.disconnect();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. There's something I don't understand though: If I omit the code from `int res` to just before `disconnect`, it no longer works. Additionally, if I leave out the print statements, the server will eliminate the resulting dead code. How come those statements are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String urlParameters = "Text to classify";
```

to

```
String urlParameters = "{\"no_of_parameters\":1,\"parameters\":{\"1\":true,\"2\":false,\"3\":true},\"service_ID\":\"BT\",\"useCase_ID\":\"SetIgnitionState\"}"; // It's your JSON-array
```

Comment: Thanks @that, one quick noob question: Where do I put my batch of texts to send in it?

Comment: What you call "batch of text"? If you want to send some array as JSON-data, you need transform your array.

Sample:

    `String[] string = {"one", "two"}; // it's a simple String array`

  As JSON-string it will looks like: 

    `{"0":"one", "1":"two"}`

  Don't forget use placeholders ("\") in Java code:

    `{\"0\":\"one\", \"1\":\"two\"}`

Answer (score 0):

First I would rename urlParameters to requestContent. The former is quite confusing as this is content not really parameters. Secondly you either have to either encode it manually or let some existing library to do it for you (Gson for example):

```
Map<String, Object> request = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
request.put("txt", "Text to classify");
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
Gson.toJson(request, writer);
writer.close();
```

Similarly back when received response:

```
Map<String, Object> result = Gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream), Map.class);
result.get("result").get("confidence")
... etc
```

Or you can create data classes for both request and response.

Answer (score 0):

To read the response, add something like to the bottom of your code:

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line+"\n");
    }
}
```

After this, StringBuilder will have the response for you to process.

To send the JSON request data, you'll need to replace:

```
String urlParameters = "Text to classify";
```

With

```
String urlParameters = "{\"no_of_parameters\":1,\"parameters\":{\"1\":true,\"2\":false,\"3\":true},\"service_ID\":\"BT\",\"useCase_ID\":\"SetIgnitionState\"}";
```

Note the \ in front of the embedded quotes inside the string.

Even better is to use a library where you can build your JSON text, like:

[JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)